# Optimising Monte-Carlo algorithm | Reduce operation on GPU & Eigenvalues problem | Many-body problem

Tags: cuda, reduce, gpgpu, montecarlo, eigenvector

This issue reminds some typical many-body problem, but with some extra calculations.

> I am working on the generalized Metropolis Monte-Carlo algorithm for the modeling of large number of arbitrary quantum systems (magnetic ions for example) interacting classically with each other. But it actually doesn't matter for the question.

There is more than 100000 interacting objects, each one can be described by a coordinate and a set of parameters describing its current state `r_i`, `s_i`.

> Can be translated to the C++CUDA as `float4` and `float4` vectors

To update the system following Monte-Carlo method for such systems, we need to randomly sample 1 object from the whole set; calculate the interaction function for it `f(r_j - r_i, s_j)`; substitute to some matrix and find eigenvectors of it, from which one a new state will be calculated.

The interaction is additive as usual, i.e. the total interaction will be the sum between all pairs.

Formally this can be decomposed into steps

1. Generate random number *i*
2. Calculate the interaction function for all possible pairs `f(r_j - r_i, s_j)`
3. Sum it. The result will be a vector `F`
4. Multiply it by some tensor and add another one `h = h + dot(F,t)`. Some basic linear algebra stuff.
5. Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, based on some simple algorithm, choose one vector `V_k` and write in back to the array `s_j` of all objects's states.

There is a big question, which parts of this can be computed on CUDA kernels.

I am quite new to CUDA programming. So far I ended up with the following algorithm

```cpp
//a good random generator
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> random_sampler(0, N-1);

for(int i=0; i\<a_lot; ++i) {
  //sample a number of object
  nextObject = random_sampler(rng);

  //call kernel to calculate the interaction and sum it up by threads. also to write down a new state back to the d_s array
  CUDACalcAndReduce<THREADS><<<blocksPerGrid, THREADS>>>(d_r, d_s, d_sum, newState, nextObject, previousObject, N);

  //copy the sum
  cudaMemcpy(buf, d_sum, sizeof(float)*4*blocksPerGrid, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  //manually reduce the rest of the sum
  total = buf[0];
  for (int i=1; i<blocksPerGrid; ++i) {
    total += buf[i];
  }

  //find eigenvalues and etc. and determine a new state of the object 
  //just linear algebra with complex numbers
  newState = calcNewState(total);

  //a new state will be written by CUDA function on the next iteration

  //remember the previous number of the object
  previousObject = nextObject;

}
```

The problem is continuous transferring data between CPU and GPU, and the actual number of bytes is `blocksPerGrid*4*sizeof(float)` which sometimes is just a few bytes. I optimized CUDA code following the [guide from NVIDIA](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) and now it limited by the bus speed between CPU and GPU. I guess switching to `pinned` memory type will not make any sense since the number of transferred bytes is low.

I used Nvidia Visual Profiler and it shows the following
[image]

the most time was waisted by the transferring the data to CPU. The speed as one can see by the inset is `57.143 MB/s` and the size is only `64B`!

The question is **is it worth to move the logic of eigenvalues algorithm to CUDA kernel?**

Therefore there will be no data transfer between CPU and GPU. The problem with this algorithm, you can update only one object per iteration. It means that I can run the eigensolver only on one CUDA core. ;( Will it be that slow compared to my CPU, that will eliminate the advantage of keeping data inside the GPU ram?

The matrix size for the eigensolver algorithm does not exceed 10x10 complex numbers. I've heard that cuBLAS can be run fully on CUDA kernels without calling the CPU functions, but not sure how it is implemented.

**UPD-1**
As it was mentioned in the comment section.
For the each iteration we need to diagonalize only one 10x10 complex Hermitian matrix, which depends on the total calculated interaction function `f`. Then, we in general it is not allowed to a compute a new sum of `f`, before we update the state of the sampled object based on eigenvectors and eigenvalues of 10x10 matrix.

Due to the stochastic nature of Monte-Carlo approach we need all 10 eigenvectors to pick up a new state for the sampled object.

However, the suggested idea of double-buffering (in the comments) can work out in a way if we calculate the total sum of `f` for the next `j-th` iteration without the contribution of `i-th` sampled object and, then, add it later. I need to test it carefully in action...

**UPD-2**
The specs are

- CPU 4-cores Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz
- GPU GTX960

quite outdated, but I might find an access to the better system. However, switching to GTX1660 SUPER did not affect the performance, which means that a PCI bus is a bottleneck ;)

Comment: You could try using [`cusolverDnXsyevd`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cusolverdnxsyevd) or [`cusolverDnXsyevdx`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cusolverdnxsyevdx) (compute only a subset of eigenvalues).

Comment: @paleonix, did you mean to call it using [Dynamic parallelism feature](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/docs/TechBrief_Dynamic_Parallelism_in_CUDA_v2.pdf)?

Comment: These are host APIs as far as I know, so you can't call them from a kernel and for small 10x10 matrices I don't expect them to perform extremely well. But it would be a way of keeping the data on the device and have at least some parallelism during these operations. More information about how many 10x10 matrices, how many eigenvalues (eigenvectors too?) per matrix and how they depend on each other (or not?) would be useful.

Comment: I would say for just a single eigenvalue problem it certainly makes sense to leave the data on the GPU and use CUSOLVER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is is it worth to move the logic of eigenvalues algorithm
> to CUDA kernel?

Depends on the system. Old cpu + new gpu? Both new? Both old?

Generally single cuda thread is a lot slower than single cpu thread. Because cuda compiler does not vectorize its loops but host c++ compiler vectorizes. So, you need to use 10-100 cuda threads to make the comparison fair.

For the optimizations:

According to the image, currently it loses 1 microsecond as a serial part of overall algorithm. 1 microsecond is not much compared to the usual kernel-launch latency from CPU but is big when it is GPU launching the kernel (dynamic parallelism) itself.

CUDA-graph feature enables the overall algorithm re-launch every step(kernel) automatically and complete quicker if steps are not CPU-dependent. But it is intended for "graph"-like workloads where some kernel leads to multiple kernels and they later join in another kernel, etc.

CUDA-dynamic-parallelism feature lets a kernel's cuda threads launch new kernels. This has much better timings than launching from CPU due to not waiting for the synchronizations between driver and host.

Sampling part's copying could be made in chunks like 100-1000 elements at once and consumed by CUDA part at once for 100-1000 steps if all parts are in CUDA.

If I were to write it, I would do it like this:

- launch a loop kernel (only 1 CUDA thread) that is parent
- start loop in the kernel
- do real (child) kernel-launching within the loop
- since every iteration needs serial, it should sync before continuing next iteration.
- end the parent after 100-1000 sized chunk is complete and get new random data from CPU

when parent kernel ends, it shows in profiler as a single kernel launch that takes a lot of time and it doesn't have any CPU-based inefficiencies.

On top of the time saved from not synching a lot, there would be consistency of performance between 10x10 matrix part and the other kernel part because they are always in same hardware, not some different CPU and GPU.

Since random-num generation is always an input for the system, at least it can be double-buffered to hide cpu-to-gpu data copying latency behind the computation. Iirc, random number generation is much cheaper than sending data over pcie bridge. So this would hide mostly the data transmission slowness.

---

If it is a massively parallel experiment like running the executable N times, you can still launch like 10 executable instances at once and let them keep gpu busy with good efficiency. Not practical if too much memory is required per instance. Many gpus except ancient ones can run tens of kernels in parallel if each of them can not fully occupy all resources of gpu.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the detailed answer. You shared some great ideas. Regarding the 1 CUDA thread, originally I thought it would need to be synced  by CPU (which will slow down the whole thing) like there must be a master kernel, which controls 10 CUDA threads. Now with dynamic parallelism feature it will not be an issue

Comment: Yep dynamic parallelism is good at efficiently handling many launches but I may be wrong about applicability of double buffering in pure cuda version. How would two stages work in parallel if they are input of each other? Overlapping random generation with kernel is ok but the 10x10 matrix calculation may not be able to start before the other kernel ends. I should edit/fix my error.

Comment: I was wondering about that too. however, for the second buffer we can still calculate the whole sum except one i-th object (from the overlapping past iteration), which will be added later.  Or even go further - perform calculations on multiple buffers in advance omitting the contribution of {i-th, j-th, k-th and etc } objects and then, sequentially update the states of them.

Comment: I will try a couple of techniques you suggested and post the results here